# Setting a Html table 'tr' width to have a different width for each cell on one row

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following table declaration:

```html
<table width="80%" style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;" width="80%" colspan="2" >This is a very long first line here, taking the entire width of the table</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border: 1px solid black;" width="10%">Comment</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black;" width="80%">My text on the comment cell</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I don't understand why my second column is as wide as the first one. I thought that by specifying the `table-layout: fixed;` property for the table, and setting the columns widths, I would obtain what I wanted, which was:

- A first row with only one cell of a width which would be 100% of the table width
- A second row with a small first cell, and a second wide second cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table-layout: fixed` allows you to set the widths of each `<th>` or the first row of `<td>` within the `<tbody>` if there's no `<thead>`. Once the widths are established, each column will conform to those widths. It's the nature of a column. If you want different widths for each row try `colspan`.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

th {
  width: 25%
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>I</th>
      <th>II</th>
      <th>III</th>
      <th>IV</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='4'>colspan="4"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan='3'>colspan="3"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'>colspan="2"</td>
      <td colspan='2'>colspan="2"</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, I was not aware that it worked like that

Answer (score 2):

In the fixed table layout, when the first row of the table can't describe the individual column widths, you need to use the col element to define those widths. So:

```css
table {
  width: 80%;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  table-layout: fixed;
}
col:nth-child(1) {
  width: 20%;
}
col:nth-child(2) {
  width: 80%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
  <table>
    <col><col>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">This is a very long first line here, taking the entire width of the table</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Comment</td>
        <td>My text on the comment cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: When does the first row not able to set it's own widths and the table not "describe" them?

Comment: @zer00ne - when the first row's cells span multiple columns.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. I would never have a table without a `<thead>` so it never occurred to me. You should add your comment to your question.+1